# Is there a way to fix my skyrim save?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I've got 130+ hours into skyrim and upon completing the burning of king olaf my game freezes within 5 minutes of loading every time. Has anyone had a similar problem and been able to solve it by any means?
It's not freezing on autosaves or any other specific action.

Comment: This is probably obvious but just for clarity, have you downloaded the latest patch from the PSN?

Comment: Have you tried saving another game after reloading your save, saving it to another slot, and THEN loading the last save again?

Comment: I will try what you suggested Bora, I found a similar suggestion in an article on the lag.

Comment: 130 hours?  That's all?  When did you buy the game, just last week?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem, when you load right before they start burning him just walk away from the area that they are burning him... try that once